# Kyber and Dilithium usage limits?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptanalysis, kyber, dilithium

What are the theoretical usage limits of Kyber and Dilithium? Are there any sources to back this up? Maximum number of encryptions/signatures allowed per key, etc.?

Comment: I suppose $2^{64}$ if not none. But I'm voting to close this Q for now, before you tell us why you believe there would be any - whether you heard it from somewhere, or why you imagined such theoretical limit in the first place. I only know SPHINCS has a limit that's so astronomical that we don't concern with it in practice.

Comment: I'm wondering how this question originated. Does this question originate from not understanding signature schemes (newbe question) or it is somehow related to a test which distinguishes hash-based signature schemes (HBS) and other PQC signature schemes?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It's probably from hearing about unauthenticated encryption/AEAD usage limits, like discussed [here](https://soatok.blog/2020/12/24/cryptographic-wear-out-for-symmetric-encryption/) and [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-aead-limits), and limited signatures for hash-based post-quantum signature schemes, like discussed [here](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/BSI/Publications/Brochure/quantum-safe-cryptography.html?nn=916626) and [here](https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/ir/8413/upd1/final).

Comment: Correct. Is it that incredulous a question?